# Add another column to Property Grid WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid

I would like to extend the Property Grid to add another column as this picture illustrated (side by side). I've searched but couldn't find any solution to this. Is there any way or workaround way of doing this? Greatly appreciated any suggestion.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to add specific behavior by adding a property? You can create a new grid inheriting from the Property Grid.

Comment: @Niraj The behavior will be the same as the one on the left. Basically adding a duplicate of the second column but with different values.

Comment: @Niraj Could you please elaborate on it more?